# Joda setJulian Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: java, calendar, jodatime

I get an illegalArgument Exception when I call the setJulianDate method in the joda time API for certain julian double values.

```
JDateTime jdt = new JDateTime(); 
JulianDateStamp jdstamp = new JulianDateStamp(julianDateDouble);
jdt.setJulianDate(jdstamp);
System.out.println(jdt);
```

When

```
Double julianDateDouble = (double)2452555.13;
```

I get the java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value too big: 1000 error. However, when

```
Double julianDateDouble = (double)2452558.67;
```

The double julian value gets converted to 2002-10-11 04:04:48.000 correctly. The same happens for a bunch of julian date values I have.

Comment: I believe this has to do with how the number `2452555.13` and others are represented in memory. The millisecond value for the format seems to reach 1000 which can't be displayed correctly and therefore throws the `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis do you know a way to solve this? I need the accuracy of the conversion only to an hour.

Comment: Not familiar with the API but I noticed one thing about your code. There's no need to explicitly cast these values like this. Floating point numbers in Java are `double` by default. `(double)2452555.13` is exactly the same as `2452555.13`. It's also possible to append the number with the letter `d` if you want to avoid confusion `2452555.13d`.

Comment: I explicitly cast the numbers because the values comes out of an external array of numbers that have no decimals at times; they are implicitly regarded as integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but everything seems to point to the precision of a floating point number. You can use the overloaded constructor for `JulianDateStamp` that accepts a `BigDecimal`.

```
BigDecimal julianDateDouble = new BigDecimal("2452555.13");
JDateTime jdt = new JDateTime(); 
JulianDateStamp jdstamp = new JulianDateStamp(julianDateDouble);
jdt.setJulianDate(jdstamp);
System.out.println(jdt);
```

prints

```
2002-10-07 15:07:12.000
```

which is validated by [this Julian Date Converter](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/JulianDate.php).

If your input is coming in the form of a `double`, use

```
Double dob = (double)2452555.13;
System.out.println(dob);
BigDecimal julianDateDouble = new BigDecimal(dob.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Now the values get converted correctly.